# How can I get all data in a unique message, from a sheet A from comparing two cells in different spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to compare two cells in sheetA and SheetB like in the screens below to get the exact results (screen).

I've run a code, but it sends me multiple messages (Each single data row in a message) instead of a single message containing all the information (See results screen).

[SheetA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3L32.png)
[image]
[SheetB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzliC.png)
[image]
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyXBq.png)
[image]
Thank you in advance.

Here's the code I used :

```
function myFunction(){

  var SheetA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetA');
  var SheetB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetB');
  var lr = SheetA.getLastRow();

  for (i = 2; i < lr+1; i++){

    var StoreB = SheetB.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var StoreA = SheetA.getRange(2,2).getValue();
    var Activity = SheetA.getRange(2,4).getValue(); 

    if (StoreA == StoreB && Activity == 'Actif'){

      var order = SheetB.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var date_li = SheetB.getRange(i,4).getValue();
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_li), 'Europe/Paris', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
      var ref = SheetB.getRange(i,5).getValue();
      var desi = SheetB.getRange(i,6).getValue();
      var quantity = SheetB.getRange(i,7).getValue();
      var livred = SheetB.getRange(i,8).getValue();
      var email = SheetA.getRange(2,5).getValue();
        
      
      const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Body');
      
      htmlTemplate.email = email;
      htmlTemplate.order = order;
      htmlTemplate.date = date;
      htmlTemplate.desi = desi;
      htmlTemplate.ref = ref;
      htmlTemplate.quantity = quantity;
      htmlTemplate.livred = livred;

      const htmlforEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

      console.log(htmlforEmail)
      MailApp.sendEmail(
        email,
        'Modification date d\'inventaire',
        "SVP Ouvrez ce mail avec le support HTML",
        {htmlBody: htmlforEmail}
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your "Results" sheet can be achieved using a Pivot Table? Please give it a try. Google has a lot of resources for that

Comment: Please share the code you tried

Comment: @Gangula I need to exctract Data via mail. Thank you for your reply

Comment: You would be wise not to refer to spreadsheet with the term 'Sheet' because in google apps script documentation the Class Sheet refers to a page or tab in a spreadsheet.  It is unfortunate that Google refers to their own products as sheets.  It's probably because the high level administrators have never read their own google apps script documentation to realize what a problem it would cause for programmers.

Comment: I hope you realize that your SheetA and SheetB are in the same spreadsheet,which seems inconsistent with your question, you will have to open at least one of them with openById().

Comment: The send mail statement is inside the for loop. That's why you are getting a mail for each row. Shift it outside the loop. You will get only one mail. But, how all the rows will be accumulated - you have to manage

Comment: You should consider collection all of the information in an object.  This process is generally caled pivoting

Comment: @Cooper I'm a beginner to google apps script, I didn't know that, thank you so much for these valuables informations, step by step and by your help, I'll be a better coder in this language.

Comment: @arulselvan Thank you so much, I didn't pay attention to this, I'll manage it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it but it will necessitate having to change the template so that it can handle a 2d array to place the data in to a table.  Fortunately, the data also includes the first row of headers for the table.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sha = ss.getSheetByName('SheetA');//reference
  const shb = ss.getSheetByName('SheetB');//order data
  const hA = shb.getRange(1,1,1,8).getDisplayValues().flat().splice(2,1);
  const vsb = shb.getRange(2, 1, shb.getLastRow() - 1, shb.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  const StoreA = sha.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  const Activity = sha.getRange(2, 4).getValue();
  const email = sha.getRange(2, 5).getValue();
  const del = { pA: [] };
  if (Activity == 'Actif') {
    vsb.forEach((r, i) => {
      let [st, order, , date_li, date, desi, quantity, livred] = r
      if (StoreA == st) {
        if (!del.hasOwnProperty(st)) {
          del[st] = [];
          del[st] = hA;//puts the titles into the data
          del[st].push([r[0], r[1], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7]]);
          del.pA.push(st);
        } else {
          del[st].push([r[0], r[1], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7]]);
        }
      }
    });
    const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Body');
    htmlTemplate.order = del[st];
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Modification date d\'inventaire', "SVP Ouvrez ce mail avec le support HTML", { htmlBody: htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent() });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @cooper, I'll test it and give you an answer how I manage it. However, as a beginner in google apps script, I didn't understand some functions. I'll do a quick research for that. Thank you again :) !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`````
function myFunction(){

  var SheetA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetA');
  var SheetB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetB');
  var lr = SheetA.getLastRow();

      var order = "";
      var date_li = ""
      var date = "";
      var ref = "";
      var desi = "";
      var quantity = "";
      var livred = "";
      var email = "";
        


  for (i = 2; i < lr+1; i++){

    var StoreB = SheetB.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var StoreA = SheetA.getRange(2,2).getValue();
    var Activity = SheetA.getRange(2,4).getValue(); 

    if (StoreA == StoreB && Activity == 'Actif'){

      order += SheetB.getRange(i,2).getValue()+'\n';
      date_li += SheetB.getRange(i,4).getValue()+'n';
      date += Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_li), 'Europe/Paris', 'dd/MM/yyyy')+'\n';
      ref += SheetB.getRange(i,5).getValue()+'\n';
      desi += SheetB.getRange(i,6).getValue()+'\n';
      quantity += (+SheetB.getRange(i,7).getValue());
      livred = SheetB.getRange(i,8).getValue();
      email = SheetA.getRange(2,5).getValue();
      
    }

      
      const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Body');
      
      htmlTemplate.email = email;
      htmlTemplate.order = order;
      htmlTemplate.date = date;
      htmlTemplate.desi = desi;
      htmlTemplate.ref = ref;
      htmlTemplate.quantity = quantity;
      htmlTemplate.livred = livred;
      const htmlforEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();


      console.log(htmlforEmail)
      MailApp.sendEmail(
        email,
        'Modification date d\'inventaire',
        "SVP Ouvrez ce mail avec le support HTML",
        {htmlBody: htmlforEmail}
      );
  }
}

````
`````